# Python: make a dict using two list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

How can I make using python a dict using two list

```
list_one_keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
```

Nested list:

```
list_two_values = [['a1var1', 'a1var2', 'a1var3', 'a1var4'], ['a2var1', 'a2var2', 'a2var3', 'a2var4']]
```

desired result a python dict:

```
thisdict = {
  "dict1"{

  "key1": "a1var1",
  "key2": "a1var2",
  "key3": "a1var3",
  "key4": "a1var4"
},
"dict2":{
  "key1": "a2var1",
  "key2": "a2var2",
  "key3": "a2var3",
  "key4": "a2var4"
}


}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something with combination of `zip`, `enumerate`, and `dict`:

```
result = {'dict{}'.format(index+1):dict(zip(list_one_keys, val)) 
                              for index, val in enumerate(list_two_values)}
```

Output:

```
{'dict1': {'key1': 'a1var1',
  'key2': 'a1var2',
  'key3': 'a1var3',
  'key4': 'a1var4'},
 'dict2': {'key1': 'a2var1',
  'key2': 'a2var2',
  'key3': 'a2var3',
  'key4': 'a2var4'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_one_keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
list_two_values = [['a1var1', 'a1var2', 'a1var3', 'a1var4'], ['a2var1', 'a2var2', 'a2var3', 'a2var4']]

d = {}
for i, sub_list in enumerate(list_two_values):
    entry_name = "dict" + str(i+ 1)
    for x, y in zip(list_one_keys, sub_list):
        if entry_name not in d:
            d[entry_name] = {}
        d[entry_name].update({x: y})

print(d)
```

small explanation:

1. iterate through the `list_two_values` sub-lists using the
   [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)
2. use [`zip`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) for parallel iteration over each sub-list(from step
   1) and `list_one_keys`

output:

```
{'dict1': {'key1': 'a1var1', 'key2': 'a1var2', 'key3': 'a1var3', 'key4': 'a1var4'}, 'dict2': {'key1': 'a2var1', 'key2': 'a2var2', 'key3': 'a2var3', 'key4': 'a2var4'}}
```

Comment: WOW!Thank you very much!
I am impressed by the speed.